# how to scan a text on paper, store it in a file and then use that info

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ocr

I am working on a project that requires me to scan (or take a picture of) a text in a paper, then process that into a text file and then use the info in the text file to trigger another action (e.g. if the first letter is "A" then...), all this in the same application. any approach would be of great help but will be perfect if I can make that happen in an android app using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to use OCR i.e. Optical Character recognition. On Android platform this libaries i know so far are listed below:-

[android-ocr](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr)

[tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)

[Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Optical Character Recognition (OCR) to accomplish your task.  You have a couple of options available:

- [Google Documents API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr)
- [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)
- [Qualcomm Vuforia SDK](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/text-recognition-feature)

The only one of those options that I have used is the Vuforia SDK so I cannot say what would be the best or easiest to use.  Vuforia is an augmented reality SDK but it has support for text recognition and it worked well when I used it but it did take me a while to setup and use.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about that android-ocr library, is very helpful.